# Ubuntu installed on laptop, want to switch to Windows with existing SSD

Tags: boot, windows, ssd

I installed Ubuntu a while ago on this laptop (ASUS N55SF). Now I have a SSD on the computer with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to switch to another SSD with Windows 8.1. I tried with just switching the SSD's from one to the other but it did not work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_but it did not work._" ? Is the SSD from another computer ? If so, Windows doesn't like being moved from one computer to a different one. Please [edit] your question and add more details. I think this is more of a Windows problem, and not an Ubuntu one - so you should probably ask your question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: When I booted with the other SSD with Windows on it did not work. I can check exactly what it said if you give me a minute. I can give you any details you want, just let me know what you need. If this is a Windows issue just let me know and I'll head somewhere else. Thanks for response!

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to know what it said.

Comment: "Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet COntroller v2.0.2.6(09/28/10)

Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.

Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_"

Comment: That probably means that the Windows bootloader is missing on the SSD - you'll probably need to boot from the Windows installation media (DVD or USB) and select "Repair computer". See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: Wow, great thanks JonasCz. If there is anything I can do for you just let me know. I will also let you know and make an edit if this fixed the problem. Returning shortly...

Comment: And do note that if the SSD came from another, different computer, Windows may not work correctly.

Comment: You are probably right, or you ARE right. I might have to reconsider my options here a little. I thank you for giving me really fast and helpful feedback. As I said before, let me know if there is anything I can do to give you my thanks. Thanks! Admin can remove this thread or mark as resolved.

Comment: @Christopher in this situation when someone resolved a problem through comments, it's common for the person who helped you to type out an answer which resolved your problem.  You can then click the grey checkmark next to his answer to accept it as the correct answer.  On forums it would be marked "solved", but, here, answers are marked as "accepted".